# Why toString() cannot be a static method?

Tags: java, class, static, access-modifiers

Sup guys, I have a simple, but bugging question.
As far as I understand, `static` basically means, that for every single instance of that class, this method will be the same, if we change it, this will change for every single instance of that class, it's also known as Class Method. Well, if I have a class that implements `toString ()` method witch a certain format, let's say:

```
public String toString() {  
    return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

Why can't it be set as static? Since this format will be the same for every single instance of that class...?

Comment: Think about x and y. If they are non-static fields, a static method cannot access them.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan so you say that if the x and y were static values, the toString() method could be set as static?

Comment: Your understanding of `static` is slightly off. `static` means that only one instance is created (at least for variables). You can access `static` variables / methods without even instantiating an object (eg `ClassName.toString()`. Also, you don't have to make a new method for each object; they all have the same method's available

Comment: No, because in class Object, toString() is not static. If you wanted, you could make a static method for it, but things like System.out.println wouldn't call it.

Comment: I wrote an answer until I realized that the question doesn't make sense. You've already defined the method once, where should you have to redefine it?

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski If x and y were static, then the toString result would be independent of the object, so it would not be much use.

Comment: @Saposhiente That probably won't be so. If you have some static method `foo()` in class `Foo`, `Foo.foo()` would do the same thing as `someInstanceOfFoo.foo()`

Comment: @Quincunx It's illegal in this case, as Sotirios says.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that you're worried about performance, about  all of your instances of your class having "excess copies" of the same function. In actuality, there is only one copy of the code for instance functions; the only difference with static is what the function can access and what can access the function.

Comment: So bottom line, you can't have a `public void static toString()` because it already exists in the Object class as `public void toString()` and each object is an extension of the Obj class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does not apply only to `toString()`

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) says

> It is a compile-time error if a static method [hides](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) an instance
>   method.

Since the instance method `toString()` is implicitly inherited from `Object`, declaring a method `toString()` as `static` in a sub type causes a compile-time error.

From an Object Oriented point of view, see the other answers to this question or [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906913/java-static-vs-instance) questions.

Comment: in that case, it applies to `equals()`, `hashCode()`, etc

Comment: @Quincunx Yes, any visible instance method.

Answer (score 5):

Because a static method cannot access instance fields. Also, `toString()` is specified by `java.lang.Object`, so you must have an instance of Object to invoke `toString()` on. Finally, if `toString()` were static, it would have to accept instances of Object (how else could you call toString() on a n instance of a class?).