# How can I change the variable from another class without using static?

Tags: java

I have tried to change the value of the variable x below by using a getter and setter.

```
package game;
public class Game {
private int x;
private int y;

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    Command command = new Command();
    command.changeX();
    System.out.println(game.getX());
}
}
```

I have another class that has a method that changes the integer x, by using the get and set method.

```
package game;

public class Command {
Game game = new Game();

public void changeX() {
    int x = game.getX();
    game.setX(x + 1);
}
}
```

When I run the program the console prints out 0, but it is supposed to be one. Then, if I try to print out the value of x using the getX method in Command right after I set the variable to one, it prints out 1. I am trying to see if there is a way I can do this without using static variables.

Comment: The instance of `Game` that your `Command` refers to is entirely different to the instance of `Game` that your `main` method refers to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating two completely separate/unique Game objects, changing x in one and expecting it to change in the other, and as you're finding out, this won't work.

Instead pass your Game object into your Command object via a setter method or constructor, and *then* change it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    Command command = new Command(game); // *** note constructor change
    command.changeX();
    System.out.println(game.getX());
}
```

---

```
public class Command {
   private Game game; //  note it's not initialized here

   // pass Game in via a constructor parameter
   public Command(Game game) {
      this.game = game;   // and set the field with it
   }

   public void changeX() {
      // now you'll be changing the state of the same Game object
      int x = game.getX();
      game.setX(x + 1);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Game();` creates an instance of `Game` object. You have one instance in `Command` and another instance in your `main` method.

Using `game.setX(int)` in instance of `Command` will only affect the `game` variable defined in that instance of `Command`.

See [Java Static vs Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906913/java-static-vs-instance)