# Iterating through an array and printing each object

Tags: java, arraylist

My array is being loaded and is printing the cards out as planned (in the order they appear in the file). When I try to cycle back through the arraylist in a separate method to check whether or not the data is there, it only prints the **last** object rather than each of them. Can anybody tell me why?

**The load method**

```
public class
    TestFrame {

//VARIABLES
private static Deck deck;
private static Card card;
private static Scanner scan;
private final static String fileName = "cards.txt";
static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

private static void Load(){

    deck = new Deck();
    card = new Card();

    // Load in the card file so that we can work with the data from cards.txt internally rather than from the file constantly.

    try(FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            Scanner infile = new Scanner(br)){

        int numOfCards = infile.nextInt();
        infile.nextLine(); // Do we need this? Yes we do. Illuminati confirmed.
        for(int i=0; i < numOfCards; i++){
            String value = infile.nextLine();
            String suit = infile.nextLine();
            Card newCard = new Card(value, suit);
            card.addCard(newCard);
            System.out.print(newCard.getValue());
            System.out.print(newCard.getSuit());
            System.out.println(" ");
            //Print out the object before cycling through again so we can see if it's working
            //We can use this to add then cards to the shuffle array at a later date
        }

    }
```

**Which prints out this when ran:**

```
ah 
2h 
3h 
4h 
5h 
6h 
7h 
8h
```

etc etc. This is the order they're in the .txt file.

**I then use these methods to display all of the cards to make sure I can manipulate the data elsewhere**

```
private static void displayAllCards(){
    Card[] cards = Card.getAll();
    for(Card c : cards){
        System.out.print(Card.getValue());
        System.out.print(Card.getSuit());
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

**and the getAll() method**

```
public static Card[] getAll(){
    Card[] brb = new Card[cards.size()];
    int tempCount = -1;
    for(Card c : cards){
        tempCount++;
        brb[tempCount] = c;
    }
    return brb;
}
```

When `getAll()` is ran, it only prints out "ks" (king of spades) which is the last card in the .txt file. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Thanks

**EDIT: CARD CLASS**

```
package uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Card {

protected static String value;
protected static String suit;
static ArrayList<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<>();

public Card(String v, String s){
    this.value = v;
    this.suit = s;
}

public Card() {

}

public static Card[] getAll(){
    Card[] brb = new Card[cardsList.size()];
    int tempCount = -1;
    for(Card c : cardsList){
        tempCount++;
        brb[tempCount] = c;
    }
    return brb;
}

public static void deleteAll(){
    cardsList.clear();
}

public static String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    Deck.value = value;
}

public static String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void setSuit(String suit) {
    Deck.suit = suit;
}

public void addCard(Card card){
    cardsList.add(card);
}
```

}

Comment: when do you populate your cards arrayList?

Comment: Show the `Card` class, please.

Comment: I know this may sound stupid, but any chance that you are not populating the `cards` arrayList? Also, your `getAll()` method can be simplified to one line `return cards.toArray(new Card[cards.size()])`

Comment: As a side note, `System.out.print(newCard.getValue()); System.out.print(newCard.getSuit()); System.out.println(" ");` can be simplified to `System.out.println("" + newCard.getValue() + newCard.getSuit());`

Comment: Can you show your `Card` class? All of it?

Comment: I've updated the OP with the Card class, sorry about that guys,

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you about using `this` on a static variable

Comment: @Naveed Thanks that's sorted the variables. I'm getting errors on method calls (such as Card.getAll()), eclipse is telling me to change getAll() to static. Any idea why/how I can get that working properly?

Comment: That is because you are calling it on the Card class, `static` methods are also called `class` methods (if that helps you understand better) so basically each time you refer to a method with class name `Card.getAll()` it will need to be static (meaning just one copy).  You use the instance (multiple copies) method by creating a new instance: `Card c = new Card()` and then `c.getAll()`

Comment: The way you have it now, you getAll method can remain static however you should change the other variables (suit and value to instance) because you can have one list of cards but you will need multiple cards in that list.  So just think static = 1, instance = multiple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
card.addCard(newCard);
```

I think this should be `cards.addCard(newCard);` instead

Comment: And thus the danger of using the singular and plural of a word in the same code block!

Comment: I thought so, too. But there is actually nothing that populates `cards` at all, so it's not supposed to get even a single value in the loop. Hence I'm not sure yours is the correct answer. I think there is something going on in the `Card` class.

Comment: Thanks. @pens-fan-69 I've updated the variable names so its not as confusing.

Comment: Also, as I commented on the other answer, there is no `addCard` method in `ArrayList<Card>`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'll update the OP with the Card class to show that there is relevant code in the which holds the values of the cards.

Comment: It now tells me "The method addCard(Card) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Card>" on addCard, would you mind explaining this in plain english please? Sorry to pester you!

Answer (score 1):

Your card class is not implemented well. The reason you are getting only the last value is because your `getters` and `String` variables are static.  There is only one copy of static variable per class.  You need to make those instance variables/methods and change your print loop to

```
for(Card c : cards){
    System.out.print(c.getValue());
    System.out.print(c.getSuit());
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906913/java-static-vs-instance) for an elaboration on static vs instance

Answer (score 1):

In `Card` the variables `suit` and `value` are declared **static**. This means that there is only one variable, shared between all cards.

When you load, you create a card. You set `suit` and `value` So they get `h` and `a` respectively. And then you print them.

Then you load the next two lines. You create a new card. But the variables are static, not part of the state of the new object, but the same `suit` and `value` that contain `h` and `a`. The new value is `2`. And it **replaces** the `a`. Then you print it. The old value is gone.

So your print in the load shows the momentary value of `suit` and `value`, but in truth, there is only one value - the last value you loaded from the file.

These variables should be part of the card's state, thus, **not static**!

Note: your IDE notices when you try to use an instance variable from a static context. For example, your `getValue` method is static. So it can't access instance variables. However, the correction is *not* to set the variable to static, but rather to change the method, which logically is supposed to be an *instance* method, to *not* `static`. It may complain again because you are calling the method from static context. Then you have to carefully look why: you are not supposed to use this method statically - you should create an instance of `Card` and call the method using the variable you created.

So, IDE suggestions to "make it static" are not the correct solution! You should make all instance-related variables and methods *not* static, and solve "static context" issues by checking why you didn't create an instance and decided to call an instance-related method statically instead.

Comment: Thank you! Me and a friend of mine were wondering why eclipse was asking for everything to be static. Can you tell me why the IDE is telling me to make methods (and thus the variables they work with) static rather than just leaving them as they are?

Comment: Okay I've used this.VARIABLE instead to cancel out the static errors but I'm still getting prompted to change methods (such as Card.getAll()) to static. would you mind explaining why this is? Thank you again, this has been a live saving response.

Comment: @JayGould I added information about that to my answer.

Comment: Oh, and the `cardsList` actually has to remain static... It's not a very good design, but at the very least, it doesn't make sense that each card should have a separate list of cards. So `cardsList` *and the methods that manipulate it* should remain static, unless you are going to make a separate class that represents a list of cards (which is the better design).

Answer (score 0):

`card.addCard(newCard);` looks like it could be `cards.add(newCard);` and also a tip, changing your indexing looks a bit nicer when you start at zero for the getAll function

```
    public static Card[] getAll(){
    Card[] brb = new Card[cards.size()];
    int tempCount = -1;
    for(Card c : cards){
        tempCount++;
        brb[tempCount] = c;
    }
    return brb;
}
```

change it to

```
    public static Card[] getAll(){
    Card[] brb = new Card[cards.size()];
    int tempCount = 0;
    for(Card c : cards){
        brb[tempCount] = c;
        tempCount++;
    }
    return brb;
}
```

Comment: Does `ArrayList<Card>` have an `addCard` method?

Comment: Good call! Yeah it should just be add then

Comment: I think there is something going on in the `Card` class where there is an `addCard` and probably an internal list, and the list named `cards` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It has an addCard method, sorry about forgetting to add it in. cards.add(newCard) isn't working but thanks for the tips!

Comment: @JayGould Please edit your question and add all the necessary data, including the source of `Card` and any changes you made to the existing source.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Can you post the Card class and perhaps the error it shows?

Comment: @JurkoGuba I;ve added in the Card class. There is no error being shown, it simply displays (prints) nothing and then shows the menu again.

Comment: Cool, did you just change the getAll method to say cardsList or is there another method that has cards?

Comment: @JurkoGuba I updated after someone commented about my variable names, the method itself hasn't been altered, they're just labeled differently so its easier to differentiate.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling `getAll()` on a specific card, however before when you had `card.addCard`, you would only be adding one card to the list since every `Card` has its own ArrayList. This is why it only would print ONE CARD. You need to use getAll() on the ArrayList you made in the file.

Make a getAll() method in the main file that uses `static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();`

```
   public static Card[] getAll(){
    Card[] brb = new Card[cards.size()];
    int tempCount = 0;
    for(Card c : cards){
        brb[tempCount] = c;
        tempCount++;
    }
    return brb;
```

This will work.

Comment: No, actually, it's the other way around. The `cardList` is static!