# Java static non static

Tags: java, eclipse

I have got a problem with my program. Eclipse writes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method umfang() from the type GeoPolygon
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method laenge() from the type GeoPolyline
```

What have I done wrong? I've got 2 errors in my App.class. Could you improve my code and explain?
Thank you in advance.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList; //import Array List (java.util)
import java.util.List;  //import List (java.util)

public class App {      //new public class App


    public static void main(String[] args) { //main methode

        GeoPoint p1 = new GeoPoint(10.681,-48.857);   // new Points (x,y)
        GeoPoint p2 = new GeoPoint(96.980,20.724);
        GeoPoint p3 = new GeoPoint(66.647,-66.558);
        GeoPoint p4 = new GeoPoint(-2.674,-58.571);
        GeoPoint p5 = new GeoPoint(40.11,-12.342);
        GeoPoint p6 = new GeoPoint(27.782,46.809);
        GeoPoint p7 = new GeoPoint(54.759,-46.709);
        GeoPoint p8 = new GeoPoint(-33.89,-90.787);
        GeoPoint p9 = new GeoPoint(15.84,-67.553);
        GeoPoint p10 = new GeoPoint(19.481,51.331);


        List<GeoPoint> list1 = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(); // Create ArrayList and add Points
        list1.add(p1);
        list1.add(p2);
        list1.add(p3);
        list1.add(p4);
        list1.add(p5);
        list1.add(p6);
        list1.add(p7);
        list1.add(p8);
        list1.add(p9);
        list1.add(p10);



        BoundingBox bbox = new BoundingBox(list1);          // get the list from BoundingBox
        double c = GeoPolygon.umfang();     //new variable c = height
        double d = GeoPolyline.laenge();        //new variable d = width

        System.out.println("Das Array beinhaltet die Punkte: " + list1 ); // This prints: "Das Array beinhaltet die Punkte" and the list
        System.out.println("Der Gesamtlaenge des Polygons betraegt (" + d +")." );  // This prints the polygons circumference
        System.out.println("Der Umang des Polygons betraegt: (" + c +")." );    // This prints the polygons area


    }
}
```

Polygon

```
import java.util.List;

public class GeoPolygon implements Geometry {

    private List<GeoPoint> Polylinelist;
    private String name;
    private double umfang;

    public double umfang() {

        umfang = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Polylinelist.size() -1 ; i++) {
            GeoPoint p1 = Polylinelist.get(i);
            GeoPoint p2 = Polylinelist.get(i + 1);

            umfang += GeoUtil.distance(p1, p2);

        }
        umfang += GeoUtil.distance(Polylinelist.get(0), Polylinelist.get(Polylinelist.size() -1 ));

        return umfang;
    }

    public GeoPolygon(List<GeoPoint> punktliste, String name) {
        this.Polylinelist = punktliste;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BoundingBox getBoundingBox() {
        BoundingBox bbox = new BoundingBox(Polylinelist);
        return bbox;
    }

    public String getName() {
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public void addGeoPoint(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        Polylinelist.add(geoPoint);
    }

}
```

GeoPolyline

```
import java.util.List;

public class GeoPolyline implements Geometry {

    private List<GeoPoint> Polylinelist;
    private String name;
    private double laenge;

    public double laenge() {

        laenge = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Polylinelist.size() - 1; i++) {
            GeoPoint p1 = Polylinelist.get(i);
            GeoPoint p2 = Polylinelist.get(i + 1);

            laenge += GeoUtil.distance(p1, p2);

        }

        return laenge;
    }

    public BoundingBox getBoundingBox() {
        BoundingBox bbox = new BoundingBox(Polylinelist);
        return bbox;
    }

    public GeoPolyline(List<GeoPoint> punktliste, String name) {    //Konstruktor
        this.Polylinelist = punktliste;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public List<GeoPoint> getPolylinelist() {
        {
            return Polylinelist;
        }

    }

    public void addGeoPoint(GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        Polylinelist.add(geoPoint);
    }

}
```

Comment: Those aren't static methods, meaning you need to utilize an instance of that class to access the methods. new GeoPolygon().umfang(); or whatever. Commenting from my phone so it's difficult but that's the idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906913/java-static-vs-instance

Comment: Please, check for already existing answers about the subject. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-static-reference-to-non-static-method

Answer (score 3):

```
double c = GeoPolygon.umfang();     
double d = GeoPolyline.laenge();
```

Those are not static methods. If you want them to be static, declare them as such.

Or, you can make an instance of the class before calling them:

eg:

```
GeoPolygon x = new GeoPolygon();
double c = x.umfang();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your App class you have the following line inside `public static void main`:

```
double c = GeoPolygon.umfang();
```

Notice how the method it is inside of is static.  Because of this you can not call `umfang()` because it is not static.  The same goes for `laenge()`.

[Read about static here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

You must create a new instance of `GeoPolygon` and `GeoPolyline` if you want to call a non-static method from it.

You can access static items directly in a class, but you can not access non-static items directly in a class.  To access non-static items, such as methods or fields, you must create a new instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the keyword static to the methods on GeoPolygon

```
    public static double umfang() {
    ...
    }
```