# Java Object with static variable instance inside Stateless Bean

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6

Is it ok to have an object inside of EAR like the Calculator class to be used as a utility for other stateless classes?

Is it a bad design? If so what appropriate approach should be applied?

```
    @Stateless
    class A{
        public void sumForA(){
            System.out.println("SUM IS : "+ (Calculator.getInstance().add(4+6)));
        }
    }

    @Stateless
    class B{
        public void sumForB(){
            System.out.println("SUM IS : "+(Calculator.getInstance().add(1+2)));
        }   
    }

    public class Calculator{

        static{
            INSTANCE=new Calculator();
        }

        private static INSTANCE;

        public Calculator getInstance(){
            return INSTANCE;
        }

        public int add(int x,int y){
            return x+y;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no such name "static variable instance", there is instance variables and static variables, you can find an example here: [Java Static vs Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906913/java-static-vs-instance).

Second, regarding your Calculator class, you need to mark the getInstance() method as static beacause you are calling it directly. And, you seem trying to use the singleton pattern, I suggest you take a look at this SO question: [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Third, in your example there is no static variable in the statless bean, and to make it simple: you are only invoking a method in the Class Calculator which has static members. So why not?! you are using your utility class inside your method, it doesn't matter if it's a stateless bean or any kind of beans (EJB session beans, CDI / JSF beans, Spring Components ... ).

Comment: Forgot to add the static before the getInstance() because I never ran it in IDE and I don't know the right terminology for the title, anyway your third answer sums up my query. Thanks

Comment: @d12ei glad it helped :)