# Using for loop to create array of objects, attributes are correct inside for loop but wrong outside for loop

Tags: java, object, object-oriented-analysis

I'd like to create an array of objects, each containing three attributes ( rules, tokens, priorities ).

To do this I have one class which contains all of the attributes in separate arrays (GenRules.java), and another class with the constructor for the object (Token.java).

Here's some code I'm running but notice how the output is different within the for loop and outside the for loop:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    // GenRules contains three arrays, one with the lexemes, another with their
    // corresponding tokens, and another with their priorities. They are separate
    // arrays but are related by index.
    int length = GenRules.length();

    // Generates an array of token objects containing all three attributes. 
    Token[] tok = new Token[ length ]; 
    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        tok[i] = Token.makeToken( GenRules.rules[i], 
                                  GenRules.tokens[i], 
                                  GenRules.priorities[i] );
        System.out.println( "i = " + i + ", " 
                                  + Token.getRule(tok[i]) + ", " 
                                  + Token.getToken(tok[i]) + ", " 
                                  + String.valueOf( Token.getPriority( tok[i] ) ) );
    }

    System.out.println( "\n" );
    int i = 0;
    for( Token t : tok ) {
        t = tok[i];
        System.out.println( "i = " + i + " " 
                + t.getRule(t) + " " 
                + t.getToken(t) + " " 
                + t.getPriority(t) );
        i++;
    }

}
```

The output generated inside the for loop is what I would expect to see:

```
i = 0, /\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/, COMMENT, -1
i = 1, d+, NUMBER, 60
i = 2, int, TYPE_INT, 60
i = 3, char, TYPE_CHAR, 5
i = 4, main, MAIN, -1
.
.
.
i = 21, (, LP, 40
i = 22, ), RP, 40
i = 23, ==, EQUALVALUE, 20
i = 24, =, EQUALSIGN, 30
```

But outside the for loop, it looks like all of the objects are initialized with the same three attributes:

```
i =  0 = EQUALSIGN 30
i =  1 = EQUALSIGN 30
i = 02 = EQUALSIGN 30
.
.
.
i = 22 = EQUALSIGN 30
i = 23 = EQUALSIGN 30
i = 24 = EQUALSIGN 30
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? For completeness I'll add the other two classes below, please feel free to knit pick at any general coding no-no's you see.

GenRules.java

```
package src;

/**
 * @author 
 * <p>
 * This class defines all of the lexing rules and tokens and has some helper functions to 
 * figure out how many rules currently exist. The arrays and values can be accessed statically, ie, no 
 * need to initialize a GenRules object. If the priority of a lexeme is 'None' it will return a '-1'. 
 * </p>
 */

public class GenRules {

/**
 * Regex comparison to a given token.
 */
public static String[] rules = { // 25 rules
        "/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/"        ,
        "d+"  ,"int","char","main"                       ,"return",
        "else","if" ,"for" ,"[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]{0,31}","{"     ,
        "}"   ,";"  ,"<="  ,"<"                          ,">="    ,
        ">"   ,"+"  ,"-"   ,"*"                          ,"/"     ,
        "("   ,")"  ,"=="  ,"="
        };  

/**
 * Token issued to token at corresponding index.
 */
public static String[] tokens = { // 25 tokens
        "COMMENT"         ,"NUMBER"     ,"TYPE_INT" ,"TYPE_CHAR"    ,"MAIN",
        "RETURN"          ,"ELSE"       ,"IF"       ,"FOR"          ,"IDENTIFIER",
        "LB"              ,"RB"         ,"SEMICOLON","LESSTHANEQUAL","LESSTHAN",
        "GREATERTHANEQUAL","GREATERTHAN","PLUS"     ,"MINUS"        ,"MULTIPLY",
        "DIVIDE"          ,"LP"         ,"RP"       ,"EQUALVALUE"   ,"EQUALSIGN"
        };

/**
 * Priority issued to a corresponding token. 
 */
public static int[] priorities = { // 25 priorities
        -1,60,60, 5,-1,
        5 ,10,10,10, 8,
        9 ,10,70,20,20,
        20,20,70,70,65,
        65,40,40,20,30 
        };

/**
 * Prints how may tokens are currently defined. If there is a mismatch in how
 * many tokens there are in comparison to priorities or rules it will return '0'.
 */
public static int length() {
    if( priorities.length == tokens.length && tokens.length == rules.length )
        return rules.length;
    else return 0;
}

/**
 * Returns all of the rules components in array form.
 */
public static String[] returnRules() {
    return rules;

}

/**
 * Returns all of the token components in array form.
 */
public static String[] returnTokens() {
    return tokens;

}

/**
 * Returns all of the priorities in array form.
 */
public static int[] returnPriorities() {
    return priorities;

}

/**
 * Prints the rule followed by token, followed by priority. Isn't formatted very well. 
 */
public static String printRules(  ) {
    String out = "";
    for( int i = 0; i < priorities.length; i++ ) {
        out += rules[i] + " " + tokens[i] + " " + String.valueOf( priorities[i] ) + "\n";
    }
    return out;
}

}
```

Token.java:

```
package src;

/**
 * @author 
 *<p>
 *This class takes the rules, tokens, and priorities described in the GenRules
 *class and encapsulates them in a single object. A token can be thought of like
 *a struct which contains one rule, one token, and one priority level.
 *</p>
 */
public class Token {

private static String rule;
private static String token;
private static int priority;

public Token() {
    // Empty like my heart.
}

/**
 * Constructor; applies values to the class attributes. 
 * @param s1 rule
 * @param s2 token
 * @param i priority
 */
public Token( String s1, String s2, int i ) {
    rule = s1;
    token = s2;
    priority = i;
}

/**
 * Takes in arguments to construct a token and generates one
 * using the constructor. Once generated it is returned to 
 * wherever it was called from. 
 * @param s1
 * @param s2
 * @param i
 * @return Returns a formed token object.
 */
public static Token makeToken( String s1, String s2, int i ) {
    Token t = new Token( s1, s2, i );
    return t;
}

/**
 * Returns the rule from a Token.
 * @param t
 * @return
 */
public static String getRule( Token t ) {
    return t.rule.toString();
}

/**
 * Returns the 'token' from a Token.
 * @param t
 * @return
 */
public static String getToken( Token t ) {
    return t.token.toString();
}

/**
 * Returns the priority value from a Token.
 * @param t
 * @return
 */
public static String getPriority( Token t ) {
    return String.valueOf( t.priority );
}

/**
 * Will print out the rule, token, and priority values given
 * an array of tokens. 
 * @param t
 */
public static void printTokens( Token[] ti ) {
    for( Token t : ti ) {
        System.out.print( t.getRule( t ) + " " );
        System.out.print( t.getToken( t ) + " " );
        System.out.print( t.getPriority( t ) + "\n" );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your fields in `Token` are static, not instance fields.  So all tokens just get set to whatever was the last token made, because static fields are effectively global variables.

Comment: May be a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906913/java-static-vs-instance

Comment: @markspace Thank you that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables in the Token class are `static` so they belong to the class, not to each individual Token object. Each time you set these variables it is overwriting the last value (which is why it always prints the last values you assigned).

```
private static String rule;
private static String token;
private static int priority;
```

Remove the `static` keyword and try again.

```
private String rule;
private String token;
private int priority;
```